# Can I affect virtual instrument settings on existing VST host?

Tags: language-agnostic, protocols, vst

Virual instruments usually have many device-specific analog parameters, which affect output sound. For example:

[image: example]

Can I manage them without writing my own vst host?

---

For example, I don't need to write a vst host to send note to it, if existing one can accept external sequencer. - I can send MIDI messages to it using NAudio, C# and virtual MIDI cable.

What feature (protocol?) corresponds to "acceptance of external sequencer", if I want not to send notes, but alter parameters mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand, but it sounds like MIDI CC messages are what you are looking for:

http://nickfever.com/music/midi-cc-list

Note that not all VST plugins respect the MIDI GM correctly (ie, the "MIDI CC purpose" column in that document).

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).